# error_bad_lines=False doesn't remove rows with extra columns

Tags: python, pandas, csv

l have a csv file that l process with pandas. l have for columns as follow :

```
df.columns = ["id", "ocr", "raw_value", "manual_raw_value"]
```

However , l have some rows which have more than five columns . For instance :

```
id             ocr       raw_value      manual_raw_value
2d704f42    OMNIPAGE    remuneration      rémunération       hello
bfa6c9f14   OMNIPAGE    35470              35470
213e1e1e    OMNIPAGE    Echeance          Echéance
```

l did the following in order not to read the rows with extra columns (like the first row)

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=",",index_col=None, error_bad_lines=False)
```

However the the rows with extra columns are kept.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another try. For easier indexing, I would rename columns, even those which are unnecessary:

```
df.columns = range(0, df.shape[1])
```

I assume, that empty places are NaN, so valid rows will have all NaN in other columns. I was not successful in searching for specific function, so I would interate through single columns and leave only those with NaN and pick only needed columns:

```
for i in range(4, df.shape[1]):
    df = df[df.iloc[:,i].isnull()]
df = df[[0, 1, 2, 3]]
```

Then rename them how you want. Hope this will help.

Comment: thank your for your answer. the target is to remove all the rows with more than four columns. Your solution tend to take all the rows even those which have more than for columns but it doesn't take the fifth column

Comment: Sorry, that I misunderstood your question. Trying to help.